# Example to show non-uniquness of wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Consider an infinite string with the initial condition 
$$u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx},~~x\in R,~~t\geq 0$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x), ~~x\in R$$
$$u_t(x,0)=g(x),~~x\in R.$$
The solution is given by 
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x-ct)+f(x+ct))+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(s)\,ds.$$
This solution is unique if $f$ is twice continuously differentiable function and $g$ is continuously differentiable function.

Question: I want an example such that $u(x,t)$ is not unique, that is, an example with two different solution satisfying the given wave equation and its initial conditions.

Attempt: Choose $g=0$ and $f(x)=|x|$, which is non-differentiable function. Suppose my wave equation is 
$$u_{tt}=u_{xx}.$$
So, the solution is given by
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(|x-t|+|x+t|).$$
This is one of the solution. Now, what is the another solution in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one (unique) solution for the example you have taken as it is a well posed problem with well defined initial data. In fact, for the general problem that you have considered, the solution when it exists, is unique. It is a direct consequence of the energy method. See [this discussion](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/schumaker/Math4540/Uniqueness_Thms.pdf) for a proof.